# T-SQL Performance of != operator against IN operator

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008-r2, inequality, in-operator

I've written a SQL Server 2008 R2 stored procedure to perform a reconciliation, and I have a reconciliation status flag (TINYINT), which can have the values 0 (New), 1 (Reconciled) or 2 (Exception).

In the procedure, I'm selecting all records that haven't been successfully reconciled into a temporary table by using the != operator:

```
SELECT FIELDS
INTO #TEMP_TABLE
FROM PERMANENT_TABLE
WHERE RECONCILIATION_STATUS != 1
```

Talking to a DBA at work, he thought that re-coding this as:

```
SELECT FIELDS
INTO #TEMP_TABLE
FROM PERMANENT_TABLE
WHERE RECONCILIATION_STATUS in (0, 2)
```

would be more performant, as we know what all the possible values of the RECONCILIATION_STATUS field can be. I couldn't find any literature backing this up and wondered if he was indeed correct?

Comment: do you see any difference in the execution plans?

Comment: Are you sure it matters?  - Worst case is that each value in the `in` clause must be compared to the candidate value, contrast this with != which is a single comparison.  What of a future value of 3?

Comment: SQL Server should be able to do index seek for inequality too, at least if your statistics are up-to-date. I would assume only a very small percentage of the rows have value other than 1?

Comment: Just a side note, a filtered index on the status field might be a good idea, if you don't already have one -- if my previous assumption on the data distribution is correct.

Comment: If reconciliation status can be more than 0,1,2 then the second statement would be quicker I think. Especially if it's indexed on that column.

Comment: JamesZ - good idea, your assumption is correct - one a record has been successfully reconciled, it will stay that way forever, so a filtered index where the status != 1 will give better performance as the table grows over time (the overhead to maintain the index won't be a problem here based on how/when the reconciliation is executed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious solution is to test out both.

First set up a sample schema:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.T', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.T;
CREATE TABLE dbo.T 
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    RECONCILIATION_STATUS TINYINT NOT NULL CHECK (RECONCILIATION_STATUS IN (0, 1, 2)),
    Filler CHAR(100) NULL
);

INSERT dbo.T (RECONCILIATION_STATUS)
SELECT  TOP (100000) FLOOR(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 3)
FROM    sys.all_objects a, sys.all_objects b;
```

Then test with no indexes

```
SELECT  COUNT(Filler)
FROM    dbo.T
WHERE   RECONCILIATION_STATUS != 1;

SELECT  COUNT(Filler)
FROM    dbo.T
WHERE   RECONCILIATION_STATUS IN (0, 2);
```

The plans for each are:

[image]

As you can see there is a negligible difference here, with no index a clustered index scan is required for both queries.

With so few possible values, a non clustered index is unlikely to be of any use unless you either include all the columns you need regularly as non key columns, or don't have much data. With a standard non clustered index on the 100,000 sample rows built as follows:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_T__RECONCILIATION_STATUS
    ON dbo.T (RECONCILIATION_STATUS);
```

The execution plan remains the same with a clustered index scan.

With other columns included as a non key index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_T__RECONCILIATION_STATUS
    ON dbo.T (RECONCILIATION_STATUS) INCLUDE (Filler);
```

The plan for `!= 1` becomes quite convoluted, and although I wouldn't place much emphasis on its importance, the estimated costs are the same:

[image]

However, the IO statistics show that the actual reads required is hardly any different:

> Table 'T'. Scan count 2, logical reads 935, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>
> Table 'T'. Scan count 2, logical reads 934, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

So thus far, there is little difference, but it really would depend on your data distribution, and what indexes and constraints you have.

Interestingly, if you create a temporary table for the test and define a check constraint on it:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#T', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #T;
CREATE TABLE #T 
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    RECONCILIATION_STATUS TINYINT NOT NULL CHECK (RECONCILIATION_STATUS IN (0, 1, 2)),
    Filler CHAR(100) NULL
);

INSERT #T (RECONCILIATION_STATUS)
SELECT  TOP (100000) FLOOR(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 3)
FROM    sys.all_objects a, sys.all_objects b;
```

The optimiser will actually rewrite this query:

```
SELECT  COUNT(Filler)
FROM    #T
WHERE   RECONCILIATION_STATUS != 1;
```

As

```
SELECT  COUNT(Filler)
FROM    #T
WHERE   RECONCILIATION_STATUS = 0
OR      RECONCILIATION_STATUS = 2;
```

As demonstrated in this execution plan:

[image]

I have not been able to replicate this behaviour on permanent tables though. Nonetheless this leads me to believe the best option is

```
WHERE   RECONCILIATION_STATUS IN (0, 2);
```

Not only in terms of performance, although it appears to be marginal or not at all in most cases, but certainly in terms of readability and future proofing for additional values.

There is however, no better way to find out than to run these kind of tests for yourself on your own data. This is going to give you a far better idea of what performs better than any hypothesis I can pull together from a small sample set of data.

Comment: I appreciate how you pointed out that the best approach is to try both .. then you did it with illustrations and explanations of the results. Very helpful. I used the IN predicate as a way to optimize some queries in the past but wasn't sure why it was slightly more performant. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Gareth. Probably one of the most thorough answers I've seen, and shows the bare facts based on the subsequent plans. It appears that in this instance, maybe future-proofing for additional values would be the main rationale for choosing one option over the other. Adding a filtered index as JamesZ suggested should also help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Alex K mentions in a comment that using the `in` clause requires two comparisons per value while using `!=` is just one. So at face value this would make the single value solution be more attractive.

I would couple this with an filtered index on the `Reconciliation_Status` column that filters `WHERE Reconcilition_Status != 1`. This will probably end up resulting in more performance gains over the long-term.

One other thing to consider is the maintainability of the code. If there is any possibility at all that more values might be allowed in this column in the future, then using the `in` solution might right away invalidate the results if the query isn't updated (since if you add `3` as a new value, the `in (0,2)` filter will exclude rows with 3, while `!= 1` will still return what is presumable the desired result.

Comment: i agree Yaakov, a filtered index will (currently) improve performance, and your point on "!= 1" will always give the desired result is correct in the current context of the reconciliation. But of course, this could change in the future (unlikely), and the code would have to be reviewed, updated and test accordingly.